# Including javascript in the top level window of Service Cloud

Tags: javascript, servicecloud, static-resources

I'm working on an integration project that requires showing the Service Cloud from a .NET control. That control generally communicates via a javascript object on the top level window. The problem I'm having is that I can only seem to define a javascript include from a tab (iframe) within the greater application.

Is there anyway to include a javascript resource from the top level window?

Comment: Why the downvote? If I need to be more specific or clarify something, I can do so. But please leave a comment.